# MLA sectionheaders

Tags: sectioning, formatting

What code would I need to get section headers as in this [PDF](https://owl.english.purdue.edu/owl/resource/747/13/), I've used the MLA usepackage but it doesn't change the headers. I've improvised with the following code previously

```
\noindent\textsc{1. sectiontitle}
```

and

```
\textit{1.1. subsectiontitle}
```

But that would not work if I wanted to use index or table of contents.

Comment: To the best if my knowledge, the package MLA you include only setup the fomating of bibliography, and not the titling styles. Depending on the importace of the difference between larex default and MLA, you could do small changes by hand in ythe prembule, or use avmore powerfull package like `titlesec`. Maybe there already exists another package doind that. If it turns out that it does not exists, if you provide a short list of the mandatory changes, one could provide you with the needed code.